# $B$-field reducion in the Kaluza-Klein mechanism

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, effective-field-theory, kaluza-klein

Given the following $d+1$ dimensional dilaton-gravity-Maxwell low-energy effective action in the target space of a bosonic string:

$$S=\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\int d^{d+1}x\sqrt{-\tilde{G}}e^{-2\tilde{\Phi}}\left[\tilde{R}-\frac{1}{12}\tilde{g}^{AB}\tilde{g}^{MG}\tilde{g}^{ND}\tilde{H}_{AMN}\tilde{H}_{BGD}+4\tilde{g}^{MN} \partial_{\mu} \tilde{\Phi} \partial_{\nu}\tilde{\Phi} \right] $$
Where $\tilde{H}$ is written in terms of the $\tilde{B}$ field:

$$\tilde{H}_{AMN}=\partial_{A}\tilde{B}_{MN}+\partial_{M}\tilde{B}_{NA}+\partial_{N}\tilde{B}_{AM}.$$

One of the coordinates is compactified such that $y\in\{x^0,x^1,...,x^d\},\quad y\sim y+2\pi r$
and using the Kaluza-Klein mechanism one can reduce the dimension and obtain in addition to the gravitational field an abelian gauge field so the metric $\tilde{g}_{MN}$ can be expressed in terms of the reduced metric $g^{\mu\nu}$ and gauge field $A_{\mu}$ in $d$ dimensions:
$$
\tilde{g}_{MN}=
\begin{pmatrix}
g_{\mu\nu}+e^{2\sigma}A_{\mu}A_{\nu} & e^{2\sigma}A_{\mu} \\
e^{2\sigma}A_\nu & e^{2\sigma} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where $\sigma$ is the radion scalar field which is added to the theory in addition to $A_{\mu}$ as a consequence the theory now describes dilaton gravity together with a gauge field and a radion in lower dimension by the following reduction:
$$\sqrt{-\tilde{G}}=e^{\sigma}\sqrt{-G}$$
$$\tilde{R}=R-2e^{-\sigma}\nabla^2e^{\sigma}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2\sigma}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$$
Assuming the dilaton field independent of the compact coordinate $y$ it is unchanged:
$$\tilde{\Phi}=\Phi$$
But how is the $B$ field reduced such that we can express $\tilde{B}_{MN}$ in terms of the reduced $B$ field $B_{\mu\nu}$?